# How to fix the "ANR" when remove a GLSurfaceView from a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

My online app had many anr about openglview,there is the callback of the main thread。

The problem class is FxView,and the class define:public class FxView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser

and I override GLSurfaceView's functions such as:
surfaceCreated,
surfaceChanged,
surfaceDestroyed,
onWindowVisibilityChanged,
onWindowFocusChanged,

and I can not do anything,except print a log info. line,perhaps there are some anr will happen when called above override functions.

FxView added to openglLayout,and I try to remove it when close activity,then there are many anr.

The called code is :

`openglLayout.removeAllViews();`
or
`openglLayout.removeView(fxView);`

Comment: - waiting on <0x047fc1fb> (a android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThreadManager)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.surfaceDestroyed (GLSurfaceView.java:1703)
- locked <0x047fc1fb> (a android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThreadManager)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceDestroyed (GLSurfaceView.java:533)
  at hl.productor.fxlib.p.surfaceDestroyed (FxView.java:89)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface (SurfaceView.java:625)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged (SurfaceView.java:250)
  at hl.productor.fxlib.p.onWindowVisibilityChanged (FxView.java:95)